# Highcharts add series, data format

Tags: json, highcharts

I have a very strange problem today, let me post the code at first. This part of code I used in last two months and works good with dynamic highcharts display. As you can see , I get the data from PHP and using JSON.parse to convert it to object, then I using them for the series data, but series1 doesn't display. I don't know what is the problem, because I have already convert the data to object, it works fine in my other pages. I stuck here for the whole day, anyone could help me with this? I will be very appreciated.

```
 $.ajax({
         ........
          success: function (data) {
                                alert(data);
                                var response = data.split("|");
                                var data_value = JSON.parse(response[0]);
                                var data_count = JSON.parse(response[1]);

                                while(chart.series.length > 0){
                                chart.series[0].remove(true);
                                }
                                var series1 = {
                                 data: data_count ,
                                 }
                                 var series2 = {
                                 data: [5260,2658],
                                 }
                            chart.addSeries(series1);
                            chart.addSeries(series2);
                            }
```

Comment: what's the `data_count` data looks like is it a array of numbers or just 1 number?? if it's 1 number the the chart will be 1 dot you wont be able to see it

Comment: can you provide the json data, you are using after parsing it?

Comment: How does your JSON look like? Can you show the format?

Comment: It's an array, if I don't use JSON.parse, it is looks like this["21","4","15"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, use Highcharts 3.0.7 version. Then you should have in console error that your data is string, while should be number. Then on a server side generate array of numbers `[21, 4, 15]`, not of strings: `["21", "4", "15"]`.

JSON.parse won't change your string elements into numbers.

Comment: Yes, that is the problem, I put the intval() for each value on the server side, then I got the chart. Sometimes those tiny mistake will cost you a lot of time. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem somewhat similar to yours but not the exact one but what I did I called the function on error as well

Try to use this

```
$.ajax({
         ........
          error:function (data) {
                                alert(data);
                                var response = data.split("|");
                                var data_value = JSON.parse(response[0]);
                                var data_count = JSON.parse(response[1]);

                                while(chart.series.length > 0){
                                chart.series[0].remove(true);
                                }
                                var series1 = {
                                 data: data_count ,
                                 }
                                 var series2 = {
                                 data: [5260,2658],
                                 }
                            chart.addSeries(series1);
                            chart.addSeries(series2);
                            }
          success: function (data) {
                                alert(data);
                                var response = data.split("|");
                                var data_value = JSON.parse(response[0]);
                                var data_count = JSON.parse(response[1]);

                                while(chart.series.length > 0){
                                chart.series[0].remove(true);
                                }
                                var series1 = {
                                 data: data_count ,
                                 }
                                 var series2 = {
                                 data: [5260,2658],
                                 }
                            chart.addSeries(series1);
                            chart.addSeries(series2);
                            }
```